# Draw a Polyline in a Google Directions Route

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-directions-api

So, basically I created a route with Google Maps using Directions. How do i decode this overview_polyline?

```
function calcRoute() {
  var waypts = [
    { location: "Sao José dos campos,SP", stopover: true },
  ];
  directionsService
    .route({
      origin: "Rio de Janeiro, RJ",
      destination: "São paulo, SP",
      waypoints: waypts,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log({ response });
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      var rotaFeita = response.routes[0].overview_polyline; // I NEED TO DECODE THIS "rotaFeita"
      google.maps.geometry.decodePath(rotaFeita) 
      console.log(rotaFeita);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log({ err });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code I get a message: `TypeError: google.maps.geometry.decodePath is not a function`.

The correct path for `.decodePath` is: [`google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#encoding.decodePath)

To use the results of that call to create a `Polyline`:

```
new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(rotaFeita),
  map: map,
  strokeColor: "black",
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 1
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kxosa53c/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
let directionsService;
let directionsRenderer;
let map;

function initMap() {
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    },
  });

  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {
  var waypts = [{
    location: "Sao José dos campos,SP",
    stopover: true
  }, ];
  directionsService
    .route({
      origin: "Rio de Janeiro, RJ",
      destination: "São paulo, SP",
      waypoints: waypts,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log({
        response
      });
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      var rotaFeita = response.routes[0].overview_polyline; // I NEED TO DECODE THIS "rotaFeita"
      var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(rotaFeita),
        map: map,
        strokeColor: "black",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 1
      });
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i=0; i< polyline.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        bounds.extend(polyline.getPath().getAt(i));
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      directionsRenderer.setMap(null);
      console.log(rotaFeita);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log({
        err
      });
    });
}
window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Directions Service</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- 
     The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
     document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
     and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
     with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
    -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```